# Android messaging

Tags: android, messaging

I am trying to create an android messaging application.This is my code and when i run it i get an error saying "Unfortunately app has stopped".

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    String message1 = ed.getText().toString();

    public void onClick(View v) { sendSMS("5556", message1); }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Also please tell me how do I see the message that has been sent on the second emulator

Comment: Are you able to read logcat? Please post the logcat error.

Comment: pls add the errorlog, then we might figure out, why this app is crashing

Comment: illeagal state exception?

Comment: Why aren't your variables in `onCreate()`, `ed` and `message1`? They are just hanging out there

Comment: In the logcat a  NullPointerException is shown.FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 2):

Add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` this permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String message1 = ed.getText().toString();
    }
```

Comment: I've tried adding them.... a new problem turned up... some out.xml file is being created

Comment: @user1675214That comes from trying to run your xml file. You need to delete the `out.xml` file and run a class file. You can change the setting in Eclipse Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching under launch operation select "Always launch the previously launched application" and that should fix that issue